# Problem to send radius authentication logs to remote host

Tags: freebsd, syslog, syslog-ng, radius, freeradius

I have installed freeradius server on FreeBSD,it sends authentication logs to syslog's local1

> ```
> #
> #  Which syslog facility to use, if ${destination} == "syslog"
> #
> #  The exact values permitted here are OS-dependent.  You probably
> #  don't want to change this.
> #
> #syslog_facility = daemon
> syslog_facility = local1
> ```

local1 logs send to /var/log/radius.log file via syslog

> local1.*                                        /var/log/radius.log

When I want to send same logs to remote host (Centos) it doesn't send

> local1.*                                        @10.155.0.141:514

When I try to send for example cron logs,it is sending without any problem.When I generate log via logger like this

> logger -p local1.info 2222222222

remote host is receive the log.I try also specify logs via process name like this

> !radius
>   *.*                                             @10.155.0.141:514

logs again not sending.I am checking it on remote host via tcpdump.If need,I can attach all config files.I am also tried to send for example local6, it is also working well.Please help to solve the issue.

Comment: Your `logger` test uses `info` level. What level is being logged by radius?

Comment: Yes it support`

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log